# Postgres advance crossing query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a challenge in postgres and spend the the whole day trying to nail it and killing me with it. I have these two tables:

```
Tracking plan
------------------------------------------------
id       | parameters                                                    | subject
1        | [{"coding":{"code":"8231-0"}}, {"coding":{"code":"82311-0"}}] | {identifier: 1, ref: 1}
2        | [{"coding":{"code":"8234-0"}}, {"coding":{"code":"82319-0"}}] | {identifier: 2, ref: x2}
3        | [{"coding":{"code":"1234-0"}}, {"coding":{"code":"1234-0"}}]  | {identifier: 2, ref: x2}


Observations
------------------------------------------------
id       | component                                                     | code
1        | [{"coding":{"code":"8231-0"}, value: x, unit: y},             |
2        | [{"coding":{"code":"8234-0"} valua: a, unit y}]               | {coding: {code : "8281-0"}}0"}}] | {coding: {code : "82311-0"}}
```

They are more complex but will try to simplify.

So basically the table tracking plan holds some control parameters. The table observations registers every update to different updates. I need a query to know the latest update on a specific parameter that belongs to that plan.

as such I was trying to do this query:

```
SELECT tp.id, o.component
FROM ecosystem.trackingplan tp
LEFT JOIN ecosystem.observation o ON (
    EXISTS (
        SELECT FROM jsonb_array_elements(tp.parameters) comp
        WHERE comp->'coding'->>'code' IN (
            SELECT comp2->'coding'->>'code' -- Changed this line
            FROM jsonb_array_elements(o.component) comp2
        )
    )
)
WHERE tp.subject->>'reference' LIKE 'Patient/%' AND tp.subject->>'identifier' = '238'::varchar;
```

but I get all parameters in one row, and some of them do not even belong to the tracking plan.

I am trying to achieve to something like this:

```
TrackingPlan | Observation |
__________________________________
1            | [{"coding":{"code":"8231-0"}, value: x, unit: y},  
2            | [{"coding":{"code":"8234-0"} valua: a, unit y}] 
3            | null
```

Basically I want to have the id. of the plan with all the latest observations for the parameters of that plan.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the result you want to achieve, based on the sample data you’ve provided. Just as an aside, your life would be a lot easier if you hold your data in a relational structure and not as json

Comment: Hi. just did it, although was already there..